# How to display custom objects in facebook open graph stories for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a project, where I'm posting custom stories on user's facebook timeline once they request a song from my app. I created an OG story on facebook developers portal. The story would look similar to,

'Kevin requested a song using myAppName'

I integrated the code and it gets posted on the wall. Works fine. Now I face two issues in the process.

1. How to pass a custom song name? Even though I send the song name as one of the parameter to FBSDKOpenGraphObject, it keeps displayed as 'Sample Album'. How would I display my own song name like,

'Kevin requested the song never say never using myAppName'

2. My second issue is. Even though the post is getting posted, I couldn't see in my timeline. However, I can see it on my Activitylog on my wall. I have turned on 'Explicitly Shared' option on the OG story.

Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** For posting a story you need to setup object and action first. In your case you have set **Requested** as action and **Song** as Object. Right?

Now for every **Song** you need to setup an object with its own properties if you want to display it in post.

- Go to your story in developer portal and click on **Get Code**
  button.
- Click on **Code for Object** and select your platform **IOS SDK** and you can see there is this property `@"og:title": @"Sample Song"`. Here you can set your song title.

[image]

- When posting an action you need to give object url of that specific song as parameter in action code. here: `[action setString:@"http://samples.ogp.me/677267592407093" forKey:@"level"];`

**2.** Before you can publish stories for people using your app, you'll have to [submit them for review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process).